# asp.net website gives error after adding to asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have Asp.net **website** and I want to use this website in visual studio 2012 **project**. How can I import my website or convert it to project ?

I have added the website files and folders to project. but somehow there are lots of errors in code behind for example:

```
Labelusername.Text = "" + Session["username"];
//Lableusername gives error

Session["project"] = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text);
// GridView1 Gives error
```

and lots of others !

Why is this happening ?

Comment: You can use classes from your website but moving pages does not make sense.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @PhilipGullick Tnx for the heads up ! I'm still kinda new to stack!

Comment: My Website is in asp.net forms and I'm trying to switch from website to web-application because i need to use X-socket's webRTC feature in my project. and I tried their API using NuGet! it wont work in website! but it works in web-application!

Comment: Do you have the full source code of your website -including the csproj- ? Or only the website (pages, bin, resources...) ?

Comment: @JoeBilly I have all source code in asp.net website ! and the website is functional!

Comment: For those that have voted to close: This question falls under the acceptable list of questions regarding "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem ! using :

[MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx)

[Dalsoft Blog](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/09/12/converting-a-asp-net-web-site-to-a-web-application-project/)

[image: Convert to Web Application]

Comment: I was about to post you the same MSDN link. Accept your answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/about